# VBA Excel condition-based negative values don't work

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to set up the different formula for negative and positive values.

My code below suppose to be valid, but only the formula for negative values work.

```
 Dim wks As Worksheet
 Dim sunString As String
 Dim rng3 As Range

 sunString = "-"

 Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

 Set rng3 = wks.Range("F2:F" & lRow)

With rng3
  If InStr(sunString, "-") > 0 Then
    Range("W2:W" & lRow).Formula = "=R2-U2-V2"
  Else
    Range("W2:W" & lRow).Formula = "=R2+U2+V2"
  End If
```

[image]

The second formula (else statement) doesn't work at all.
What is wrong here?

Comment: What is `rng3`?  You have not assigned anything to it (or to `lRow`)....  And your test is currently equivalent to `If InStr("-", "-") > 0 Then`

Comment: You need to provide more details, including the data.

Comment: I have added the rng3 data

Comment: The `With rng3` is not used for anything, you dont reference it at all inside the with block.  Did you intend for the `InStr` or the `.Formula` to look at some value inside `rng3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a single formula that includes the condition and get rid of the unneeded looping?

```vb
Sub LoopRange()
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    lRow = wks.Cells(wks.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rng = wks.Range("W2:W" & lRow)

    rng.Formula = "=IF(F2<0,R2-U2-V2 ,R2+U2+V2)"

End Sub
```

If the data in column F is not numeric you could use this formula to check for `-`.

```vb
rng.Formula = "=IF(LEFT(F2)=""-"",R2-U2-V2 ,R2+U2+V2)"
```

Comment: It still picks up only the second formula R2+U2+V2

Comment: What exactly do you have in column F? Is the data numeric or text?

Comment: see the screenshot above. It's the numeric text I guess. Not a number but the text string.

Comment: I tried also something like this:
rng5.Formula = "=IF(F2='*-*',R2-U2-V2 ,R2+U2+V2)"
but I am getting Object defined or application defined error

Comment: I've added to my answer to include a formula that will check for text values starting with `-`.

Comment: Yes, I see. It works now. I should have treated it as the string.